# Issue with Clerk auth() helper

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js, clerk

I have a issue with Clerk auth() helper ([auth() doc](https://clerk.com/docs/quickstarts/nextjs#auth)) with react and next 13 (app router).  When attempting to retrieve both the userId and user from auth() `const { userId, user } = auth();` , I observe that the userId holds a valid value containing the user's ID. However, I encounter an issue with user, as it appears to be undefined.

Answer (score 1):

Just came across the same problem, the following worked for me.

```
const { userId } = auth();
const user = await currentUser();
const email = user?.emailAddresses[0].emailAddress
```